# Unable to receive push notifications using QuickBlox

Tags: javascript, push-notification, quickblox

I am trying to send push from web (Javascript) the push message is successfully added to queue on the quickblox account and the status is as sent but I am not receiving it on the device (iPhone). When I send push from the web console I am able to receive it successfully. Please tell me what is wrong with the code or any setting is required.

[image]

The code to send push is as follows:

```
var params = {
                login: .....,
                password: .....
            }
QB.createSession(params, function(err, result) {
                if(!err){

                    var pushCustomParams = {
                        message: 'Message sent successfully',
                        ios_badge: 1,
                        ios_sound: 'ringtone.wav',
                        user_id: app.caller.id

                    }

                    var params1 = {
                        notification_type: 'push',

                        user: {ids: [recp_id]}, // recipients.
                        environment: 'development', // environment, can be 'production' as well.
                        message: QB.pushnotifications.base64Encode(JSON.stringify(pushCustomParams)) // See how to form iOS or Android spesific push notifications
                    };

                    QB.pushnotifications.events.create(params1, function(err, response) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);

                        } else {
                            // success


                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var params1 = {
    notification_type: 'push',
    push_type: 'apns', // http://quickblox.com/developers/Messages#Create_event
    user: {ids: [recp_id]},
    environment: 'development',
    message: QB.pushnotifications.base64Encode(JSON.stringify(pushCustomParams))
};
```

I hope that this will help.